# ffmpeg: How to chain vstack with other options in _filter_complex

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am using an RTSP input stream and divide it in two identical. On the first one I just do a scaling, on the second one I do a scaling and a close up as well. So both streams [a] and [b] have the same dimensions aferwards:

```
-filter_complex "[0:v]split=2[in1][in2];[in1]scale=800:600[a];[in2]crop=640:360:700:500,scale=800:600[b]" \
```

No I am trying to create a stream from [a] and [b] called [c] to stack both together:

```
-filter_complex "[0:v]split=2[in1][in2];[in1]scale=800:600[a];[in2]crop=640:360:700:500,scale=800:600[b];[a][b]vstack=inputs=2[c]" \
```

While the first one works, I get the following error message for the second one:

```
Output with label 'a' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.
```

How can I chain the operations to that I can map a third stream an process it  with

```
-map "[a]"
-map "[b]"
-map "[c]"
```

Comment: Each pad label can only be used once as an input and once as an output. You already used `[a]` once as the input label of `vstack` so you must split `[a]` to use it for both `vtstack` and `-map`.

Answer (score 0):

@kesh: Thanks!

I modified it like this and it works:

```
-filter_complex "[0:v]split=2[in1][in2];[in1]scale=800:600[a];\ 
 [in2]crop=640:360:700:500,scale=800:600[b];\
 [a]split=2[a1][a2];[b]split=2[b1][b2];[a1][b1]vstack=inputs=2[c]" \

-map "[a2]" ...
-map "[b2]" ...
-map "[c]" ...
```